# How to query database(s) on daily schedule and generate an email report with the results?

Tags: database, scheduled-task, reporting

I have a website that runs off  a Node web server, a Redis server for temporary storage, and a Postgres database. Once a day, I would like to run a batch of Redis and Postgres queries to generate a daily report of key usage statistics, tabulate the results, and distribute this report via email. I'm wondering what is a recommended way to:

a) execute multiple Redis and Postgres queries, tabulate the results, and email them out.

b) reliably run the above script on a fixed schedule, say every 24 hours, in a Linux environment (specifically, I'm running the Amazon Linux AMI).

I'm coming from a web development background, so my initial instinct for part (a) is to write a separate Node program that performs all these tasks in succession. Is that all there is to it, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm coming from a web development background, so my initial instinct for part (a) is to write a separate Node program that performs all these tasks in succession. Is that all there is to it, or is there a better way?

Nothing wrong with that. You schedule it with cron to run it on the desired scheduled.